# How do I hook into the rails 3.1 template location logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'd like to override the default convention for locating server templates. I've been digging around ActionView (FileSystemResolver, lookup_context, etc) but the location of this logic is escaping me.

My goal is to make sharing server and client javascript templates easier. I plan to do this by extending ActionView to search for and handle JSTs in the asset pipline.

To do this, I'd like to run some code after a traditional template isn't found but before a missing template exception is thrown. Instead of throwing an exception, I'd check the asset pipeline for the template in question and handle it with a custom JstTemplateHandler.

Does anyone have any idea where to begin?

Answer (score 0):

action_view.javascript_expansions Registers the expansions set up by config.action_view.javascript_expansions and config.action_view.stylesheet_expansions to be recognized by Action View and therefore usable in the views.